# How can I listen for 'usb device inserted' events in Linux, in Python?

Tags: python, linux, usb

I'd like to write a Python script for Amarok in Linux to automatically copy the stackoverflow podcast to my player. When I plug in the player, it would mount the drive, copy any pending podcasts, and eject the player. How can I listen for the "plugged in" event? I have looked through hald but couldn't find a good example.

Comment: Wow, can you believe we used to listen to podcasts on devices that did not have an always-on broadband connection to the internet?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

**Update**: As said in comments, Hal is not supported in recent distributions, the standard now is udev, Here is a small example that makes use of glib loop and **udev**, I keep the Hal version for historical reasons.

This is basically the [example in the pyudev documentation](http://pyudev.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/pyudev.glib.html#pyudev.glib.MonitorObserver), adapted to work with older versions, and with the glib loop, notice that the filter should be customized for your specific needing:

```
import glib

from pyudev import Context, Monitor

try:
    from pyudev.glib import MonitorObserver

    def device_event(observer, device):
        print 'event {0} on device {1}'.format(device.action, device)
except:
    from pyudev.glib import GUDevMonitorObserver as MonitorObserver

    def device_event(observer, action, device):
        print 'event {0} on device {1}'.format(action, device)

context = Context()
monitor = Monitor.from_netlink(context)

monitor.filter_by(subsystem='usb')
observer = MonitorObserver(monitor)

observer.connect('device-event', device_event)
monitor.start()

glib.MainLoop().run()
```

***Old version with Hal and d-bus:***

You can use D-Bus bindings and listen to `DeviceAdded` and `DeviceRemoved` signals.
You will have to check the capabilities of the Added device in order to select the storage devices only.

Here is a small example, you can remove the comments and try it.

```
import dbus
import gobject

class DeviceAddedListener:
    def __init__(self):
```

You need to connect to Hal Manager using the System Bus.

```
        self.bus = dbus.SystemBus()
        self.hal_manager_obj = self.bus.get_object(
                                              "org.freedesktop.Hal", 
                                              "/org/freedesktop/Hal/Manager")
        self.hal_manager = dbus.Interface(self.hal_manager_obj,
                                          "org.freedesktop.Hal.Manager")
```

And you need to connect a listener to the signals you are interested on, in this case `DeviceAdded`.

```
        self.hal_manager.connect_to_signal("DeviceAdded", self._filter)
```

I'm using a filter based on capabilities. It will accept any `volume` and will call `do_something` with if, you can read Hal documentation to find the more suitable queries for your needs, or more information about the properties of the Hal devices.

```
    def _filter(self, udi):
        device_obj = self.bus.get_object ("org.freedesktop.Hal", udi)
        device = dbus.Interface(device_obj, "org.freedesktop.Hal.Device")

        if device.QueryCapability("volume"):
            return self.do_something(device)
```

Example function that shows some information about the volume:

```
     def do_something(self, volume):
        device_file = volume.GetProperty("block.device")
        label = volume.GetProperty("volume.label")
        fstype = volume.GetProperty("volume.fstype")
        mounted = volume.GetProperty("volume.is_mounted")
        mount_point = volume.GetProperty("volume.mount_point")
        try:
            size = volume.GetProperty("volume.size")
        except:
            size = 0

        print "New storage device detectec:"
        print "  device_file: %s" % device_file
        print "  label: %s" % label
        print "  fstype: %s" % fstype
        if mounted:
            print "  mount_point: %s" % mount_point
        else:
            print "  not mounted"
        print "  size: %s (%.2fGB)" % (size, float(size) / 1024**3)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    from dbus.mainloop.glib import DBusGMainLoop
    DBusGMainLoop(set_as_default=True)
    loop = gobject.MainLoop()
    DeviceAddedListener()
    loop.run()
```

Comment: I'm getting an error with this code:

dbus.exception.DBusException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.freedesktop.Hal was not provided by any .service files.

Do you think you could help me?

Comment: @EtienneLepage-Lepitre Hal is deprecated now, generally this solution won't work any more :(

Comment: Added solution using udev.

Answer (score 10):

Here is a solution in 5 lines.

```
import pyudev

context = pyudev.Context()
monitor = pyudev.Monitor.from_netlink(context)
monitor.filter_by(subsystem='usb')

for device in iter(monitor.poll, None):
    if device.action == 'add':
        print('{} connected'.format(device))
        # do something very interesting here.
```

Save this to a file say `usb_monitor.py`, run `python monitor.py`. Plug any usb and it will print device details

```
→ python usb_monitor.py 
Device('/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-6/1-6:1.0') connected
Device('/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.0') connected
```

Tested on Python 3.5 with `pyudev==0.21.0`.

Answer (score 7):

I haven't tried writing such a program myself, however I've just looked at the following two links (thanks Google!), which I think will be of help:

- [dbus-python tutorial](http://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-python/doc/tutorial.html) (which talks about how to use Python to access D-Bus)
- [HAL 0.5.10 Specification](http://www.marcuscom.com/hal-spec/hal-spec.html#interfaces) (which talks about how HAL publishes events to D-Bus)

In particular, read about the `org.freedesktop.Hal.Manager` interface, and its `DeviceAdded` and `DeviceRemoved` events. :-)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 4):

I think D-Bus would work as Chris mentioned, but if you're using KDE4, you might use the Solid framework in a manner similar to the KDE4 "New Device Notifier" applet.

The C++ source for that applet is [here](http://kollide.net:8060/browse/Plasma/applets/devicenotifier/devicenotifier.cpp?r=21574), which shows how to use Solid to detect new devices.  Use PyKDE4 for Python bindings to these libraries, as shown [here](http://techbase.kde.org/Development/Languages/Python/Using_PyKDE_4).