# Detect when a USB device is connected in C

Tags: c, linux, usb

I am new to C and am trying to write a program that syncs files on my computer to a USB device. It currently works my me cd'ing to the directory that the device mounts to and typing "myprog init" which creates a .myprog file. The idea then is that when a USB device is connected my program checks for the .myprog file, if it finds it then it syncs. Problem is that I can't figure out how to detect when a new USB device is connected.

I am writing the program for Linux (I'm using Ubuntu 9.04) and using GCC.

Thanks for any help :)

Answer (score 4):

Look into **udev** documentation for this ([writing udev rules](http://www.reactivated.net/writing_udev_rules.html)).

Also have a look at [this stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/589841/upstart-calling-script-for-inserted-usb-drive).