# Bash script to detect when my USB is plugged in and to then sync it with a Directory

Tags: linux, bash, usb, udev

Is there a Bash script and/or daemon that I can write that will detect a specific USB drive and then sync that drive with a directory?

Answer (score 23):

For future reference, here's how to run a bash script upon detection of a USB drive.

Connect your device and run `lsusb` to retrieve the device's info. You should see something similar to this:

> ```
> $ lsusb
> Bus 002 Device 039: ID 0bc2:2100 Seagate RSS LLC
> ```

In this case, the vendor ID of the device is 0bc2 and the product ID is 2100.

Now you can create your UDEV rule using a text editor of your choice.

> $sudo vi /etc/udev/rules.d/85-my_usb_device_rule.rules

And add this:

> ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="usb", SYSFS{idVendor}=="0bc2",
>   SYSFS{idProduct}=="2100", RUN+="/home/myhome/my_script"

`/home/myhome/my_script` is the path to your script which it would do whatever you want.

To make sure the detection script will execute right away, run this command to reload the UDEV rules:

> $sudo udevadm control --reload-rules

This was tested on Fedora 14.

Comment: I used this with Crunchbang Linux 11(waldorf)[debian based], but I had to change 'SYSFS' to 'ATTR' to get it to work. This guy posted a good method of debugging udev... http://www.jpichon.net/blog/2011/12/debugging-udev-rules/

Answer (score 6):

I didn't do it myself, but you can try `udev` rules like this:

```
# Hitachi SimpleDrive mini, model HTS545050B9A300 (500 GB USB HDD)
SUBSYSTEM=="block", ATTR{size}=="976768002", ATTRS{product}=="SimpleDrive mini", ATTRS{serial}=="2512009121920487", ACTION=="add", RUN+="/lib/udev/local.usb.hdd.sh add $devpath"
```

Place it in `/etc/udev/rules.d/90-local.rules` or similar place, certainly dependable on your OS.

Comment: Is it possible to use UUID and do away with all the rest of those attributes?

Comment: sorry, i don't know -- this is on my own todo list yet :)

Comment: Hi. It works. Thanks. What about when it is plugged out? Changing "add" to "remove" didn't help.

Answer (score 3):

Here is [an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/469243/how-can-i-listen-for-usb-device-inserted-events-in-linux-in-python) python deamon that you could use for the listening part, then copying the files to your directory shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Try to refrain from using external link because that external link may expire.

Answer (score 0):

There are excellent answers here already but depending on your use case, it could be as simple as
`[ -d /run/media/$USER/USB_STICK ] && do_stuff`

`USB_STICK` here is the label of the usb stick.