# How to invoke a method when a USB device is plugged in?

Tags: python, python-3.x, methods, usb

What's the best way to invoke a method in a running Python 3 application when a USB input device is plugged in?

Comment: Probably depends on your operating system

Comment: Linux and Windows 10.

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4273252/detect-inserted-usb-on-windows

Comment: Thanks for the link, but this seems to be for Windows only. Is there a more platform-independent way to do this?

Comment: One of the comments there includes a link to [How can I listen for USB device inserted events in Linux in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/469243/how-can-i-listen-for-usb-device-inserted-events-in-linux-in-python/471099#471099)

Comment: Thanks again for the link, but this seems to be for Linux only.

Comment: There isn't going to be a one-size fits all solution.  You'll likely have to implement a different version for evey operating system you want to target, and then have the program select the correct one once it is running.  Or write some installer that selects the correct implementation.

Comment: That's a pity, but obviously necessary. Thanks!