# Capture device attach detach notifications

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

Need to know how to capture device attach /detach events in windows , For linux  some interfaces are already present but didnt get interface to capture device events like if we connect USB device then we can get notification in our python application that USB device with  attached

Checking pywin32 if there is any interface already present

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4273252/detect-inserted-usb-on-windows

Comment: this is not working on my machine seems service not available