# How to shut down gobject main loop properly in python?

Tags: python, multithreading, dbus, gobject

I find myself confronted with a gobject for the first time while trying to listening to dbus. I found this piece of code teaching me how to set up a main loop.

[How can I listen for 'usb device inserted' events in Linux, in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/469243/how-can-i-listen-for-usb-device-inserted-events-in-linux-in-python/471099#471099)

But what I need now is a way to stop it. The main loop has a quit function and I know how to call it from a keyboard interrupt exception. But how do I make it stop, when I put this main loop into a thread?

Or more general: What is the proper way to make this loop run independently, but also exit when the main function exits?

I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't know anything about python but in general you should pass the `loop` variable to the calling thread (your main function) and then `loop.quit()` from there when you are done.

To pass the loop variable you have basically two options:

1. the easy way: initialize `loop` with `gobject.MainLoop()` before forking, so it is available from both threads;
2. the hard way: pass the value to the main thread after having initialized it in the loop thread.

An example (in C) of passing data between threads is shown by the [GCond documentation](http://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Threads.html#GCond) (`push_data()` and `pop_data()`).