# Make Python 3 recognize USB drive

Tags: python-3.3, usb-drive

I'm running Python 3.3 and I'm wondering how to have my program recognize a USB Drive and give the option to open it. Can this work?

Comment: Why isn't your operating system handling it?

Comment: I think that this is what you are looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/469243/how-can-i-listen-for-usb-device-inserted-events-in-linux-in-python

Comment: It is. I just wanted to see if it could be done, and how it could be done!